# CUDA atomicAdd across blocks

Tags: cuda

I cannot get the `atomicAdd` function to work over all blocks. It turns out that the following kernel code gives me the total number of threads in a block (`< 5000` for example):

```
__global __ void kernelCode(float *result)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (index < 5000)
    {
        atomicAdd(result, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me how to add something to a value but without allocating the whole array of `1.0f`?  This is because I'm using this code on a system with very limited resources - every bit counts.

Comment: Your code works fine.. have a look .. http://pastebin.com/daAGkZZu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code can work across multiple blocks without allocating an array of `1.0f`.  The `if (index < 5000)` statement is not intended to limit you to a single threadblock.  It is intended to make sure that only legitimate threads in the entire grid take part in the operation.

try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define TOTAL_SIZE 100000
#define nTPB 256

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void kernelCode(float *result)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (index < TOTAL_SIZE)
    {
        atomicAdd(result, 1.0f);
    }
}

int main(){

  float h_result, *d_result;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cuda malloc fail");
  h_result = 0.0f;
  cudaMemcpy(d_result, &h_result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 1 fail");
  kernelCode<<<(TOTAL_SIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(d_result);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
  cudaMemcpy(&h_result, d_result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2 fail");
  std::cout<< "result = " << h_result << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You can change `TOTAL_SIZE` to any number that will conveniently fit in a `float`

Note that I typed this code in the browser, there may be typographical errors.

Comment: I ran your code but it turns out that the result is 0, as if the kernel function didn't change anything...

Comment: I left out proper [cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).  Probably there is something wrong with your setup.  However I have tested this code and it works properly in a correctly set up machine.  I've updated the code now to do the same thing but include CUDA error checking.  If you compile and run it, you will likely get an idea of what is wrong.  You may also want to try running `nvidia-smi -a` at a command prompt to get an idea if the GPUs are properly installed and available.

Comment: Hey, I reinstalled CUDA 5.5 and it worked in VC++ but still, Mathematica gives as a result the number of threads in a block if say TOTAL_SIZE is bigger than this number which is the case here because 5000>1024(the maximum allowed number of threads in a block).